# Access hardware information

Tags: java, lan

I want to write code in java for getting hardware information of any system in LAN network on server.  How can I do this? Is there is special methods to access hardware information?

Comment: Refer this link, it may help you.. http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0580.html

Answer (score 1):

The system properties (see `java.lang.System`) provide some details about the OS and the JVM, but that's as far as plain Java goes. The JVM is an abstraction layer that hides most of the hardware-specific details.

The only way to collect the hardware details of remote systems is to call some platform-specific commands (e.g. `lspci` and `lsusb` on Linux), format the output (e.g. XML) and exchange those data using your favorite protocol and API (e.g. HTTP and Servlet).

Comment: yes, that's all there is to it when it comes to Standard Java. Otherwise, you'd have to depend on external libraries or call some C Code through JNI